# How to enable narrowing warnings in CodeBlocks?

Tags: c++, codeblocks, compiler-warnings, type-narrowing

I'm writing c++ program using codeblocks IDE

```
int main()
{
int i =0;
int f = 3.14;
i = f; //must give me a warning message, possible loss data.
}
```

Why the compilation not show a narrowing warning message?
How to enable that?

Note: I have fixed my compiler options as -std=c++11 -Wall

Comment: try `-Wconversion`

Comment: Another option is to write `i = {f};` , braced list enforces non-narrowing

Comment: @M.M thanks it's worked correctly
Any flag can I set to show all warnings ?

Comment: You could try `-Wall -Wextra`; IMO some warnings are more harmful than not as they complain about good code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## in the <sup>other compiler options</sup> put `-Wconversion`

## ( code::block 16 )

[image]

for:

```
int i =0;
int f = 3.14;
i = f;
```

> warning: conversion to ‘int’ alters ‘double’ constant
>   value [-Wfloat-conversion]

---

Some useful warning that I use always:

[image]

`-Wall -Weffc++ -Wextra -pedantic -Wfatal-errors -pedantic-errors`